# How to compute $\lim_{ x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2-x}}{\sqrt[3]{x+2}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}}$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to compute the following limit?

$$\lim_{ x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2-x}}{\sqrt[3]{x+2}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}}$$

In the context of the book I am reading, I must use some change of variables or multiply the expressions by some "conjugate". I tried to multiply it by $\left(\sqrt{2-x}+\sqrt{x+2}\right)$ to obtain:

$$\frac{2 x}{\left(\sqrt[3]{x+2}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}\right)
   \left(\sqrt{2-x}+\sqrt{x+2}\right)}$$

And I tried to make the following change of variables $2+x =t^6$ and then I obtained:

$$\frac{t^3-\sqrt{4-t^6}}{t^2-\sqrt[3]{4-t^6}}$$

But I couldn't go much farther than this. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Multiply by $\sqrt[3]{(x+2)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(2-x)^2}+\sqrt[3]{(x+2)(2-x)}$ and then you are basically done.

The idea is that $A^3-B^3=(A-B)(A^2+AB+B^2)$

More in general, https://brilliant.org/wiki/factorization-of-polynomials/ (sorry if it is brilliant, it's the first I found). Very helpful trick though.

Answer (score 2):

Use **L'Hôpital's** rule.
With

$$f(x){\mapsto }\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2-x}$$

$$g(x){\mapsto }\left(x+2\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}-\left(2-x\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

we compute the limit of the quotient of the first derivatives

$$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=\underset{x\to 0}{\lim }\, \frac{\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x+2}}+\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2-x}}}{\frac{1}{3 (x+2)^{2/3}}+\frac{1}{3 (2-x)^{2/3}}}=\frac{3 \sqrt[6]{2}}{2}$$

Comment: Hopital rule should NEVER be used. It is just bad practice. If you can use it, you can also use Taylor which has looser conditions and is less computationally intensive, often.

Actually, taylor has his own use when you have a limit with inside an integral. That is rare, though

Comment: Sorry, when i studied about 40 years ago i learned it in this way. And it provides the right solution.

Comment: Sure it does! Mine was more of a suggestion. It is better to use Taylor because learning the basic cases will allow you to apply it much faster than hopital. Moreover, keep in mind that Taylor, especially with the Lagrange rest,  gives you a neat approximation of the function that you can use even when you are not specifically interested in limits. I do really recommend you try never to use Hopital, and instead exercise only on Taylor. This said, hopital does have its own usage: when you have a limit of [integral]/[expression] or similar, you can derivate the integral, which is very neat!

Comment: @SimoneLicciardi Can we use Taylor series to compute limits? I mean, I was expecting it to be possible, but never tried and kinda thought that it would yield a computational mess. It's surprising to me that it could be even better than L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: It is extremely better. Because the fact is that you already know the expansion of many functions and combining them is much less computationally hard than finding the derivatives (morally, if you need to apply hopital many times, it will take you easily 10x the time than taylor). Limits are their most common usage actually. Take x-sinx/x^3 for example. I am soon opening a post about this.

Comment: Moreover, since Harish did steal my answer I would really appreciate if you checked my hint as the accepted answer. @RedBanana

Answer (score 1):

Hint

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2-x}}{\sqrt[3]{x+2}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}}$$
$$=\frac{(\sqrt[3]{x+2} )^3-(\sqrt[3]{2-x})^3  }{  \sqrt[3]{x+2}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}}$$
$$=\frac{(\sqrt[3]{x+2}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}) ((\sqrt[3]{x+2} )^2+(\sqrt[3]{2-x})^2+ \sqrt[3]{x+2}\sqrt[3]{2-x}) }{  \sqrt[3]{x+2}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}}$$
$$  =(x+2)^{2/3} +(2-x)^{2/3}+ \sqrt[3]{4-x^2}   $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2-x}}{\sqrt[3]{x+2}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}}$$
Recall that $(1+x)^{\alpha}\sim 1+\alpha x$ for $x\to 0$:
$$\sqrt{2+x}-\sqrt{2-x}\sim \sqrt{2}+\frac{x}{2\sqrt 2}-\sqrt{2}+\frac{x}{2\sqrt 2}=\frac{x}{\sqrt 2}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{x+2}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}\sim \sqrt[3] 2+\frac{x}{3\cdot 2^{2/3}}-\sqrt[3] 2+\frac{x}{3\cdot 2^{2/3}}=\frac{\sqrt[3]2x}{3}$$
Hence your limit is:
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{2-x}}{\sqrt[3]{x+2}-\sqrt[3]{2-x}}\sim \frac{x}{\sqrt 2} \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]2x}\to\frac{3}{2^{5/6}}=\frac{3\sqrt[6] 2}{2}$$